# How can I alter the colour of single letters across the whole web?

Tags: browser, text, colors

I am running an experiment in which we are trying to train people to be synaesthetes (they have additional experience of colour associated with numbers or letters).

I wondered if anyone has some advise about the easiest way to modify a web browser, such as firefox, so that just 10 letters A-J would always be displayed in a specific colour on any page they visited on the web?

Much appreciated

Comment: What part of this question is java specific?

Comment: I think they won't develop synaesthetic symptoms but just go crazy (I would). ^^ For your question: I think you would need the source code of an existing (opensource) browser and change the source such that it meets your requirements. Then compile it and distribute it to your participants.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this (cross-browser):

For example you could define a -element in a stylesheet to have a different color.
When loading the document, you check via JavaScript/jQuery the whole document (but only the contents of tags like ) for your specified letters and add the -tag f.e. around them.

Not the best solution, but a way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), a FireFox plug-in designed to do this kind of thing.  There are lots of pre-made scripts available at http://userscripts.org/, and several of them look like they'd help you figure out how to write your own to re-color single letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just an abstract rough draft of a blueprinted preliminary form of a beta version of a potential solution: using the `javascript:` prefix of links in a bookmark as follow.

1. Create a new entry in your bookmarks toolbar
2. In the URL input, copy/paste the following line: `javascript:var html = document.body.innerHTML; html = html.replace(/([a-j])/ig, '<span style="color: red;">$1</span>'); while(html.match(/(<[^>]*)<[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/[^>]+>([^>]*>)/g) != null) {html = html.replace(/(<[^>]*)<[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/[^>]+>([^>]*>)/g, '$1$2$3');} document.body.innerHTML = html;`
3. Give your bookmark a name (e.g. "A-J to red") and save
4. You can now visit any website and click on that bookmark, which will put all letters between a and j in red

In a more digest way:

```
// get the content of the body
var html = document.body.innerHTML;
// surround any letter between a and j by a <span></span>
html = html.replace(/([a-j])/ig, '<span style="color: red;">$1</span>');
// but it also replaces a-j letters within html tags
while(html.match(/(<[^>]*)<[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/[^>]+>([^>]*>)/g) != null) {
    // so if there are html tags within other html tags, delete the created <span></span>
    html = html.replace(/(<[^>]*)<[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/[^>]+>([^>]*>)/g, '$1$2$3');
}
// and replace the innerHTML of the body
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

That's really not a final solution, but yeah, maybe you could work on it to improve the results.

PS: don't try with IE...